# List all secrets with plain text from a key vault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I know that you could get the plain text for a specific secret in azure key vault with a command like this:

```
$a = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName MyKeyVaultName -Name "SecretName"
$a.SecretValueText
```

But is it possible to list all secrets and the plain text value? This just shows a blank string for the secret value:

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName MyKeyVaultName | Select-Object Name,SecretValueText
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to create a loop around secrets:

```
$q = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'xxx'
$q.foreach{ Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $_.VaultName -Name $_.Name }.SecretValueText
```

Comment: Thank you! Doing like this also shows the name of the secret: $q.foreach{ Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $_.VaultName -Name $_.Name } | Select-Object Name,SecretValueText

Comment: This only shows secret names, not the values for me

Comment: the answer was here for 3.5 years already and isn't downvoted, so I assume you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

With a newer version of Az modules.

To see both a name and value for each secret stored in the Azure KeyVault, you can try this out:

```
    $secrets=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vaultName'
    $secrets | % {Write-Output "$($_.name) $($(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $_.VaultName -Name $_.Name).SecretValueText)" }
```

Comment: This only shows secret names, not the values for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this commands en powershell.

```
$secrets=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vaultName'
$secrets | % {Write-Output "$($_.name) |  $(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $_.VaultName -Name $_.Name -AsPlainText)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet lists Secret Name and its value in plain text.

```
$kv_secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName fer-mpca-p-000 

foreach ($sec in $kv_secrets) { 
    $secret_name = $sec.Name
    $secret_value = $(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sec.VaultName -Name $sec.Name -AsPlainText)
    Write-Host "$($secret_name) | $($secret_value)"
}
```