# List all keyvault secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to know if there is a way to list down all secrets, keys, certificates inside azure keyvault. I can check on portal but that takes lot of time if I have to export this info in excel.

Anyway I can do with powershell ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76675668/1176573).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/get-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module is probably your best bet.

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "vaultname" | Select Name
```

Change `vaultname` to the name of your vault and it will show you the names of all the items stored in the given vault. You can also adjust the `Select` to get back all the data you need, or pipe to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1) directly.